# How many nodes use Parity vs Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

I saw a lot of code examples use geth but someone said to me parity is now even more popular than geth. Are there any statistics about how the nodes for Ethereum are generated - either using geth or parity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EtherNodes.org](https://www.ethernodes.org/network/1) would seem to suggest that there are still twice the number of Geth nodes as there are Parity nodes.

Specifically, as of 13 April 2018:

- Geth: 9804
- Parity: 4780

Including other clients as well, there's a total of 16436 nodes.

Comment: It is interesting to see the distribution of nodes by OS and by client.